# using hibernate to get objects in form of list

Tags: java, list, hibernate, web-applications, javadoc

I'm trying to get objects from database using hibernate class. but it cannot find mehod ".list()" it says "Javadoc not found". I don't know how to use this method.

```
List users= session.createQuery("FROM User WHERE Email=:email AND Password=:password")
            .setParameter("password", password)
            .setParameter("email", email).list();
```

Comment: "*`List users`*" - [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Alongside with this change, type the query: `session.createQuery("FROM User WHERE Email=:email AND Password=:password", User.class)` --- Use `.getResultList()`, not `list()`.

Comment: It doesn't have that method, I think the problem is how to add its library

Comment: @Turing85 `.getResultList()` exists in `javax.persistence.Query` class, not in `org.hibernate.Query`. `javax.persistence.EntityManager` creates `javax.persistence.Query`  and `org.hibernate.Session` creates `org.hibernate.Query`

Answer (score 0):

1) check that `createQuery()` method returns object of `org.hibernate.Query` class

in all versions of the Hibernate method `.list()` exists:

old Javadoc
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()

new Javadoc
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html

2) `List users` - never use raw types, because collections with a type(`List<User>`) gives you compile-time type checking, thus prevents errors in runtime-time.

Answer (score 0):

The displaying of "Javadoc not found" from Editor mean it cannot find documentation for class/method. It doesn't prevent compile/running code.

Just ignore that message and try to compile/run the code.